# MarkerClusterer is marker in cluster?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I put markers into clusters:

```
var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    zoomOnClick : false,
    maxZoom : 13,
    gridSize : 100
});
```

And i have 15 markers. 10 of these are in clusters in the map. How to determine if the marker is in a clusters.

```
var clusteredMarkers = markerClusterer.getTotalMarkers();
for(i = 0; i < clusteredMarkers.length; i++) {
    if(isInCluster((clusteredMarkers[i])) {
        clusteredMarkers[i].infobox.close();        
    }
}
```

How to define a function like isInCluster(marker) that infobox is open in only markers, that are not in any cluster (i.e. 5 infoboxes have to be visible)?

Comment: Which MarkerClusterer library are you using? MarkerClusterer or MarkerClusterePlus, or other?

Comment: i use markerclusterer.js v3: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js

Comment: I personally will try to get the clusters this way:
`var clusters = markerClusterer.clusters_;`
and then loop and foreach cluster use the getMarkers() method. If it return more than one marker then close their infowindow, else if it return only one marker it not really a cluster

Comment: It does not help. clusters.length gives 0 instead of 3 but i have 3 clusters containing that contains 2, 3 and 5 markers accordingly.

Comment: this is strange, look at line 764 of the source code, the clusters_ member contains the Cluster objects which have the getMarker method. Maybe this array is filled async, can't read the whole code now, try to manually call redraw method and then read the clusters_ property or to read the clusters_ property after a timeout interval

Answer (score 8):

The `MarkerClusterer` will set a marker's map to `null` if it is in a cluster, so that it is no longer displayed on the map. The `MarkerClusterer` will then set the marker's map back to `map` anytime it is no longer in a cluster. You could try checking each of your markers:

```
var mapOptions = {            // Notice that mapZoom is not set
    center: new google.maps.LatLng( 19, 19 ),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( "map_canvas" ), mapOptions );
var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer( map, markers, { ... });

//Whenever the map completes panning or zooming, the function will be called:
google.maps.event.addListener( map, "idle", function() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var mrkr = markers[i];
        if ( mrkr.getMap() != null ) {
            mrkr.infobox.open(); 
        }
        else {
            mrkr.infobox.close(); 
        }
    }
}

//Now that map, markerClusterer, and the "idle" event callback are in place,
//set the zoom, which will trigger the "idle" event callback 
//after the zoom activity completes,
map.setZoom( 19 ); //Or whatever is appropriate

//Thereafter, the callback will run after any pan or zoom...
```

Obviously, the state of the markers is likely to change after a zoom-in, zoom-out, or any other viewport change, so you will have to re-check after viewport changes.

Comment: How to use better. It does not work. All markers' getMaps() are no null's.

[code]
markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
  zoomOnClick : false,
  maxZoom : 13,
  gridSize : 100
 });
 var markerArray = markerClusterer.markers_;
 for ( var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++ ) {
  if ( markerArray[i].getMap() == null ) {
   alert(markerArray[i]);
   //the marker IS in a cluster, handle accordingly
  } else {
   //the marker IS NOT in a cluster, handle accordingly
  }
 }
[/code]

Comment: First, I would stop accessing `MarkerClusterer.markers_` directly. Use the `markers` var you have created to work with the markers. Second, if you try to run through the markers immediately after creating the `MarkerClusterer`, it may not have completed the clustering process. That was the point in the final sentence in my answer, you want to define an event listener for the map, listening for the `bounds_changed` event is probably best, and then perform your traversal of the markers after the viewport has changed.

Comment: Also, just so you know, if you switch to the [MarkerClustererPlus](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerClustererPlus) library, it provides better event tools; it provides both `clusteringbegin` and `clusteringend` events.

Comment: Maybe you can puth the whole code here? Also in markers[i].getMap() does not work here if i tried.

Comment: I've adjusted the code to fully depict what I we have been discussing. It's untested, but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Hi,
I need a solution where infoboxes are always displayed with markers. If the markers go into clusters, then infoboxes should disappear as well, when zooming markers out from clusters then infoboxes should open with them as well. my sample code: http://88.196.132.133/markerclusterer/

thanks for the help Sean

Comment: Just added a bit more logic - is that what you need?

Comment: Ok - great; glad to hear that everything is working. If you like my answer, upvote it by clicking the arrow above the number next to the answer. If you feel that my answer addresses your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark shape next to the answer.

Comment: I have a question, how to solve problem. If i zoom the map in, then infoboxes begin to blinking and map centers to particular place?

Comment: Are you saying that when you zoom in, you want the InfoBoxes to start blinking and then you want to center the map at a particular location? If that _is_ what you are asking, it's customary to open a new question. That way, other developers on the site can get the benefit of both questions and the answers you get. It's also customary to upvote this answer if you like the answer. And to accept this answer if you believe it addressed your question. It benefits both of us and lets other developers know that the question has been answered. I'll be than happy to help with your new question.

Answer (score -2):

Look this example http://88.196.132.133/markerclusterer/, it does not work properly with infoboxes. It is necessary that all the markers (if they are out of clusters) is always displayed with infoboxes.
The problem is also that all the infoboxes open for a moment when loading a page.

Comment: Maibe you can give a proper code here, instead of http://88.196.132.133/markerclusterer/? That boxes are not blinking and it does not hold the center near Grindsted in Denmark. Thank you.